# Setting and accessing namespaces in python lxml

Tags: python, namespaces, lxml

I am writing a script that processes a `rdf:skos` file with python3 and `lxml`:

I learnt that I need to pass to the findall procedure the namespaces that the XML mentions. (Ok, strange, since the XML files lists these in the header, so this seems like an unnecessary step but anyway).

When calling

```
for concept in root.findall('.//skos:Concept', namespaces=root.nsmap):
```

that works, because a root.nsmap is constructed by `lxml`.

But then later in my code I also need to perform a test on `xml:lang`

```
for pl in concept.findall(".//skos:prefLabel[@xml:lang='en']", namespaces=root.nsmap):
```

and here python tells me

```
SyntaxError: prefix 'xml' not found in prefix map
```

Ok, true, in my skos file there is no extra declaration for the xml namespace. So I try to add it to the root.nsmap dict

```
root.nsmap['xml'] = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
```

but that too doesn't work

```
nsmap = {'rdf': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#', 'uneskos': 'http://purl.org/umu/uneskos#', 'iso-thes': 'http://purl.org/iso25964/skos-thes#', 'dcterms': 'http://purl.org/dc/terms/', 'skos': 'http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#', 'rdfs': 'http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#'}
```

Seems I am not allowed to modify the `root.nsmap`?

Anyone an idea how this is done? I have processed tons of XML in the past with Perl XML::Twig which is very very comfortable and I assmue, the Python community has (at least) similarly comfortable ways to do that ... but how?

Any hint appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying [`root.nsmap`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#nsmap) has no effect. But you can create another dictionary and modify that one. Example:

```
from lxml import etree

doc = """
<root xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#">
   <skos:prefLabel xml:lang='en'>FOO</skos:prefLabel>
   <skos:prefLabel xml:lang='de'>BAR</skos:prefLabel>
</root>"""

root = etree.fromstring(doc)
nsmap = root.nsmap
nsmap["xml"] = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" 

en = root.find(".//skos:prefLabel[@xml:lang='en']", namespaces=nsmap)
print(en.text)
```

Output:

```
FOO
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! works like a breeze. Issue solved.(Still, if I may, I find it strange that lxml a) forces me to make special arrangements for the default namespace "xml" that the original XML file does not even declare and b) that I can't extend the nsmap that the parser creates ...) Anyway, glad it works. Thanks again!!

Comment: I agree that it is strange that you are forced to declare the "xml" prefix in the Python code when it does not need to be declared in the XML file.